# Are there any specialized databases for aggregate queries?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database, nosql

Are there any specialized databases - rdbms, nosql, key-value, or anything else - that are optimised for running fast aggregate queries or map-reduces like this over very large data sets:

```
select date, count(*)
from Sales
where [various combinations of filters]
group by date
```

So far I've run benchmarks on MongoDB and SQL Server, but I'm wondering if there's a more specialized solution, preferably one that can scale data horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For certain kinds of data (large volumes, time series) kx.com provides probably the best solution: kdb+. If it looks like your kind of data, give it a try. Note: they don't use SQL, but rather a more general, more powerful, and more crazy set-theoretical language.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, the real issue has less to do with aggregate query performance, which I find good in all major databases I've tried, than it has to do with the way queries are written.

I've lost count of the number of times I've seen enormous report queries with huge amounts of joins and inline subquery aggregates all over the place.

Off the top of my head, the typical steps to make these things faster are:

1. Use window functions where available and applicable (i.e. the `over ()` operator). There's absolutely no point in refetching data multiple times.
2. Use common table expressions (`with` queries) where available and applicable (i.e. sets that you know will be reasonably small).
3. Use temporary tables for large intermediary results, and *create indexes on them* (and analyze them) before using them.
4. Work on small result sets by filtering rows earlier when possible: `select id, aggregate from (aggregate on id) where id in (?) group by id` can made much faster by rewriting it as `select id, aggregate from (aggregate on id where id in (?)) group by id`.
5. Use `union/except/intersect all` rather than `union/except/intersect` where applicable. This removes pointless sorting of result sets.

As a bonus the first three steps all tend to make the report queries more readable and thus more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle, DB2 Warehouse edition, and to a lesser degree SQLServer enterprise are all very good on these aggregate queries -- of course these are expensive solutions and it depends very much on your budget and business case whether its worth it.

Comment: any particular functionality that you feel was missing from current versions of SQL Server that are available in DB2 and Oracle?

Comment: Not so much functionality as performance issues. Both DB2 and ORACLE can in thier different ways spread the load over several machines. SQLServer is pretty much limited to one machine.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any [OLAP database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing), this is exactly the type of thing they're designed for.

Comment: From what I've seen, this looks perfect for huge scale. But when you're scale isn't so much, what do you suggest from the popular DBs?

Answer (score 2):

OLAP data cubes are designed for this. You denormalize data into forms that they can compute on quickly. The denormalization and pre computation steps can take time, so these databases are typically built only for reporting and are separate from the real time transactional data.